# Generic Xcode Archive created instead of iOS archive for react-native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, publish

My react native project creates Generic Xcode Archive instead of iOS app archive. I am unable to publish app on Apple store as unable to archive app correctly. 
Please help in this regard why it creates Generic archive instead of iOS app archive? and how to resolve this issue?